# How to use multiple parse apps using PM2 and Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, parse-platform, pm2, parse-server

I'm wondering on how I can migrate different apps to the same server, I'm using PM2 to ensure it's always running.

Here is my ecosystem file

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "parse-wrapper",
    "script"      : "/usr/bin/parse-server",
    "watch"       : true,
    "merge_logs"  : true,
    "cwd"         : "/home/parse",
    "env": {
      "PARSE_SERVER_CLOUD_CODE_MAIN": "/home/parse/cloud/main.js",
      "PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI": "mongodb://parse:password@your_domain_name:27017/database_name?ssl=true",
      "PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID": "your_application_id",
      "PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY": "your_master_key",
    }
  }]
}
```

Shoud I use the same ecosystem file or should I create a new one and run ??

> PM2 start

How to configure the URL to different apps in Nginx

```
location /app1/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/parse/;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

Comment: I've tried adding a second App to the array that points to the same "script", "name" "cwd" and then changed the env variables but then when I fire up pm2 it just restarts continuously. Have you made any progress with this?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I have mine setup, but you should also create a new ecosystem for each api you have running. But for the .info file in the NGINX you should list all of your app locations like this:

```
        location /app1/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/parse/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
}
        location /app2/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1338/parse/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your ecosystem.json file? Also how would you setup the parse-dashboard with this configuration if you had to?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to set up multiple parse apps with the following configuration:

My ecosystem.json:

```html
  {
    "apps" :
  [

  {
      "name"        : "first app",
      "script"      : "parse-server",
      "ignore_watch": ["logs"],
      "watch"       : true,
      "merge_logs"  : true,
      "cwd"         : "/root/parse-server/",
      "env": {
        "PARSE_SERVER_CLOUD_CODE_MAIN": "/root/cloud/main.js",
        "PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/DATABASE_NAME",
        "PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID": "<APP_ID>",
        "PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY": "APP_MASTER_KEY",
        "PORT": "1337",
        "PARSE_SERVER_URL": "http://localhost:1337/parse",
      }
  },

  {
      "name"        : "second app",
      "script"      : "parse-server",
      "ignore_watch": ["logs"],
      "watch"       : true,
      "merge_logs"  : true,
      "cwd"         : "/root/parse-server/",
      "env": {
        "PARSE_SERVER_CLOUD_CODE_MAIN": "/root/pace-app/cloud/main.js",
        "PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/logisticsDB",
        "PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID": "<APP_ID>",
        "PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY": "<APP_MASTER_KEY>",
        "PORT": "1338",
        "PARSE_SERVER_URL": "http://localhost/app2",
      }
  },

  {
        "name"        : "dashboard",
        "script"      : "parse-dashboard",
        "watch"       : true,
        "merge_logs"  : true,
        "cwd"         : "/usr/local/bin/",
        "args"        : "--config /root/dashboard.json --allowInsecureHTTP true"
  }]
 }
```

My dashboard.json:

```html
{

"allowInsecureHTTP": true,
"apps": [
    {
        "serverURL": "http://somedomain:1337/parse",
        "appId": "<APP_ID>",
        "masterKey": "<APP_MASTER_KEY>",
        "appName": "APP 1"
    },
    {
        "serverURL": "https://somedomain/app2",
        "appId": "<APP_ID>",
        "masterKey": "<APP_MASTER_KEY>",
        "appName": "App 2"
    }
],
"users": [
    {
            "user": "user",
            "pass": "pass",
            "apps": [{ "appId": "<APP_ID>" }]
    },
    {
            "user": "admin",
            "pass": "admin",
            "apps": [{ "appId": "<APP_ID>" }]
    }
]
}
```

My /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default was something similar to what user1959311 has.

Hope it helps.

Cheers